# How to manage activity for playing a music

Tags: android, android-intent

I am working on live radio app.
I parse list of channels and show in list view , My problem is when i click on particular channel first time than it plays that channel according to assign link. but when you go out of application and come back and again you click on same channel (Which is playing currently ) it restart the media-player and start playing it again.

so to solve this problem i used manifest "singleTask" to solve this problem.But now when i try to click another link ( other than currently playing) than it wont play the current selected channel from Listview item and its assign link..

So can anybody please tell me How can i have code for activity and service to solve this problem , I am student so i don't have much experience.

Also I am checking for internet if you are connected to internet than it parse the json otherwise it will show message but it only check once when you start your application So how can i check net connection background?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a `Service` to play music in background.

There is a sample project called `RandomMusicPlayer` embedded with the SDK which could help you a lot to achieve it. (In Eclipse: New Project > Android > Android Sample Project)

Comment: My problem is i want this "when i click on list item it take me to Play_screen activity and from that activity i called start service and stop service..for every list item i am calling same activity to start and stop service..with channel link enclosed in "put extra"..and because of singletask it won't take called get extra again when i click on another item of list view..your example are for creating and binding service..bt i have service already..in spotify when u select song from list it takes your to play screen when you select another song than it change the playing song.i want same"

Answer (score 0):

Move your player to the Service, bind it in activity a send commands from your activity, there is plenty tutorials for this.

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298946/android-service-controlling-mediaplayer)

[Service activity communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463175/how-to-have-android-service-communicate-with-activity)

[Service media player](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Media/UsingServicetoplaymediafile.htm)

Comment: My problem is i want this "when i click on list item it take me to Play_screen activity and from that activity i called start service and stop service..for every list item i am calling same activity to start and stop service..with channel link enclosed in "put extra"..and because of singletask it won't take called get extra again when i click on another item of list view..your example are for creating and binding service..bt i have service already..in spotify when u select song from list it takes your to play screen when you select another song than it change the playing song.i want same"

Comment: I suggest remove singletask and in activity which have play controls (the one after click on listview) ask service if playing and which channel, setup GUI to playing state, in service check if play intent is for the same channel - ignore or another, change channnel. If I understand you correctly